# GCP Data Fusion error running Dataproc pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are trying to deploy a basic instance of Data Fusion in the our Architecture. We are able to deploy it but when we run a simple *NY Times Best Selling Books Under $10* pipeline from the Hub/Pipelines we get an error when hit `Run` button.

We have successfully deployed this pipeline in a fresh project but when we deploy it into our primary project in our Org structure we are getting an error for VM-to-VM communication:

> 2020-04-22 23:12:08,272 - WARN  [provisioning-service-8:i.c.c.r.s.p.d.DataprocProvisioner@194] - Encountered 1 warning while creating Dataproc cluster:
>   The firewall rules for specified network or subnetwork would likely not permit sufficient VM-to-VM communication for Dataproc to function properly. See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/network for information on required network setup for Dataproc.

We have reviewed and checked the documentation suggested but still haven't been able to find the port or IP Address to allow.

Answer (score 0):

Because Dataproc VMs run many of OSS services on VMs and each of them use a different set of ports there are no predefined list of ports and IP addresses that you need to allow communication between in the firewall rules. What you should do instead is to allow intra-cluster communication between all VMs over all ports and IP addresses in your internal cluster network.

Also, this is a warning that could have a false-positives, so if your pipeline executes correctly even with this warning than you can ignore it.